# Enabling iPad developer mode without xCode

Tags: ipad, ios7

I have a mobile webapp I want to test on an iPad (iOS 7).

In particular, I am trying to simulate a bad network.

I am following the instructions here:

http://natashatherobot.com/simulate-bad-network-ios-simulator/

Is it possible to enable developer mode without xCode (which requires a Mac)?